# In Qlikview, Find no of stores that have achieved the budget

Tags: qlikview, set-analysis

In Qlikview, I am trying to get no of stores that have achieved budget for this year to date.

I run the report every day morning for the year upto end of yesterday.

The expression below is not working due to double quotes within double quotes.

I tried replacing inner double quotes with single quotes but no luck.

Any suggestions / ideas?

```
count({<StoreNo={"=sum( {<DayNo={"<=$(vYesterday_DayNo)"}>}SalesAmount)> sum( {<FYear={DayNo={"<=$(vYesterday_DayNo)"}>}[Budget Amount])"}>}StoreNo)
```

Comment: I have good responses for this question at Qlik community thread. https://community.qlik.com/message/1329176#1329176

Answer (score 1):

This long expressions are usually hard to debug at once. I suggest you to divide it into several parts and see which part fails. Eg: make a pivot table with dimension "StoreName" and expression "SalesAmount". Then keep adding expressions as columns, each of them getting more complex (that is, using set analysis). You will probably found which one is wrong pretty quickly. Instead, if they are correct, maybe the count is what is wrong. 
Another good idea is to try that with a very reduced set of information so that you can easily check manually if the expressions are calculating properly.

*Edit: if you need more specific help, you will need to provide more specific info such as the meaning of all the variables appearing in the expression, their expected values, etc.